# Laravel 9 Auth Issue on web and API on the same app

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-8

I'm trying to create auth for both web and API in the same laravel app. But web auth is not working properly...I've an issue with SESSION_DOMAIN when I remove this from .env file then both auth works fine but when I keep this into the .env file then web auth is not working properly, getting 419 | Page Expired error.

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ZSiB/A6U0zU8Vn2x8gbNnU1prcw90xQBfqm3JS9qp+I=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=xpert_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

This is my .env file codes

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class UserController extends Controller {
    // user registration
    public function register(Request $request) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
            'cpassword' => 'required|string|min:6|same:password',
        ], [
            'cpassword.same' => 'Password confirmation does not match.',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'errors' => $validator->errors()
            ], 200);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'role' => 0
        ]);
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $user->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken
        ], 200);
    }

    // user login
    public function login(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:5'
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'validationError' => true,
                'message' => $validator->errors()
            ], 200);
        }

        $creditentials = [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'role' => 0
        ];

        if (!Auth::attempt($creditentials)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Invalid credentials'
            ], 200);
        }
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'user' => Auth::user(),
            'token' => $user->createToken('API Token')->plainTextToken
        ], 200);
    }

    // user profile
    public function profile() {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'user' => Auth::user()
        ], 200);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'User loggedOut successfully'
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

This is my API auth codes

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\Question;
use App\Models\Section;
use App\Models\Test;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller {

    // view login page
    public function index() {
        return view('index');
    }

    // view dashboard page
    public function adminDashboard() {

        $products_count = Product::count();
        $sections_count = Section::count();
        $tests_count = Test::count();
        $questions_count = Question::count();
        return view('admin.dashboard', [
            'products_count' => $products_count,
            'sections_count' => $sections_count,
            'tests_count' => $tests_count,
            'questions_count' => $questions_count,
        ]);
    }

    // handle admin login
    public function adminLogin(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|max:50|min:5'
        ]);
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        if (auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            if (auth()->user()->role === 1) {
                return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
            }
            // else {
            //     return redirect()->route('super.dashboard');
            // }
        }
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['message' => 'Invalid credentials']);
    }

    // handle admin logout
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        auth()->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect()->route('admin.login.page');
    }
}
```

This is my web auth codes

```
Route::middleware('guest')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.login.page');
  Route::post('/admin-login', [AuthController::class, 'adminLogin'])->name('admin.login');
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
  Route::get('/dashboard', [AuthController::class, 'adminDashboard'])->name('admin.dashboard');
});
```

This is my web.php routes file

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    // unprotected routes
    Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [UserController::class, 'register']);

    // protected routes
    Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/profile', [UserController::class, 'profile']);
        Route::post('/logout', [UserController::class, 'logout']);
    });
});
```

And this is api.php file code

Comment: I think this has to do with the csrf token, maybe exclude the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware from the web routes?

Comment: How to do that can you please share the codes

Comment: After both your web routes, add `->withoutMiddleware(\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class);` and see if that works.

Comment: Tried but not working

Answer (score 0):

Share you codes more .

Usually 419 error page in Laravel is related to CSRF and which request is coming maybe considers as cross site request forgery attacks .